# Bash + check for file exist with a path home ~

Tags: bash, file

I haven't found anything to deal with this particular situation. Maybe there is a easy way that I'm overlooking instead of checking for a string to catch this scenario.  When I check an input for existence of a file, if the input is `~/filecheck` , this won't work. I get negative results while the file is in my home folder. Any suggestions for improvement to any part of the script I will definitely appreciate. I also have to use an input instead of a argument. Thanks for any help.

my test script

```
read -p "Enter: " input
echo $input
if [ -f $input ]; then
                read -p "Do you REALLY want to delete this file?:" input2
                if [[ $input2='y' || $input2 = 'Y' ]]
                 then
                        rm -f $input
                elif [[ $input2='n' || $input2='N' ]]
                then
                        exit
                else
                        echo "Invaild Option"
                        exit
                fi

else
 echo Invaild Option!
 exit
fi
```

Comment: It _does_ work: `input` expands to `~/filecheck` so `[ -f $input ]` will check whether a file named `filecheck` exists in the directory `~` in the current directory. What else were you expecting? it seems you don't really understand when the expansion of `~` occurs. Just like `$HOME/filecheck` would give you the same kind of result.

Comment: ~ doesn't expand since its an input. Please try it so you can understand my problem. I actually didn't catch that difference until anubhava pointed it out below.  It makes sense since the input isn't in bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are entering input string as `~/filecheck` shell doesn't expand tilde while using condition with `-f` in `[ -f $input ]`

You can use it this way **but it is not recommended and potentially dangerous as arbitrary commands can be run by user**:

```
if [[ -f $(bash -c "echo $input") ]]; then
    echo "file exists"
fi
```

**EDIT:** As per the comments below to avoid risky `bash -c` you can use:

```
if [[ -f "${input/\~/$HOME}" ]]; then
    echo "file exists"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. This is a good and clear answer. It explains what the problem was with a clever solution. Thanks again.

Comment: Not recommendable... just like the other answer with `eval`. It's very dangerous to call commands on un-sanitized user input.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf  O that's interesting.  What could potentially happen?  buffer overflow of some sort?  You have any suggestions to sanitizing the input or any resources or solutions? Appreciate your help.

Comment: @user3590149 just try to input `; ls`, just for fun, and you'll see that you can execute any arbitrary command—think of a guy entering `; rm -rf ~` and wipe out a lot of stuff—that's why I say it's dangerous. (Don't try it at home, even under parental guidance). I have no solutions to give you, except to build a converter of your own that will replace any potential leading `~/` with the expansion of `$HOME/`: that is `input=${input/#~\/$HOME/}`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I can understand this point but I'm having problems recreating what your suggesting. So I go into program 'sh program' , next I have prompt, I put into the prompt '~/filename; ls' , my output is what is expected.  'Invalid option'.  I have tried other options.  '; ls' and doesn't work either.  I can see what potentially could happen but I just want see happen though.

Comment: @user3590149 you don't see it since the output of `ls` is eaten by the `[[` keyword. If you want to see something mildly evil happen, try instead the following input: `; touch gniourf` and you should have a file named `gniourf` in your directory.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Wow worked.  ITS EVIL>>>VERY EVIL!...haha  Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have tilde expansion in this part of the program without using something based on `eval`—and you don't want to do that with user input. So, your poor-man solution will be to substitute any potential leading `~/` with the expansion of `$HOME/`. Here's the adaptation of your script in an arguably better style:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -e -p "Enter: " input
input=${input/#~\//$HOME/}   # <--- this is the main idea of this answer (and it's rather poor)
echo "$input"
if [[ -f $input ]]; then
    read -e -p "Do you REALLY want to delete this file? " input2
    if [[ ${input2,,} = y ]]; then
        rm -f -- "$input"
    elif [[ ${input2,,} = n ]]; then
        exit
    else
        echo "Invalid Option"
        exit
    fi

else
    echo "Invalid Option!"
fi
exit
```

Now, out of curiosity, why are you spending time to make a wrapper around `rm`? you're making a clunky interface to an already existing program, without adding anything to it, only rendering it less powerful and less easy to use.

Comment: Reading a book with exercises. Some elementary maybe but I'm trying to take each example very serious and try to find complete solutions. Even if the book doesn't want that level of detail. I find I learn more this way. Thanks again.

Comment: @user3590149 Out of curiosity, which book is it?

Comment: I misspoke this question came of worksheet, don't know the origin. But I have two book references that I'm using "The Unix Programming Environment" by Brian Kernighan and "Learning the bash Shell: Unix Shell Programming" . You have any recommendations?

Comment: Your answer takes away relative path in respect to the location of the program being executed. That's okay though.

Comment: @user3590149 I don't know either of the books. If you want some modern Bash insight, there's the [Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) by _very_ knowledgeable guys. I can guarantee that they only show good practices in there!

Comment: @user3590149 What do you mean by it takes away relative path?

Answer (score 0):

If all what you want it's to ask the user before deleting, you can use:

```
rm -i
```

This will give you appropriate error in the case file does not exist.